# Interactive input in Ansible playbook

Tags: module, ansible, redhat, satellite

I'm trying to automate the satellite and capsule upgrade from Ansible. I'm able to convert the commands into ansible plybook without any issues except the below two commands, need your help to incorporate these commands into playbook:

```
satellite-maintain upgrade check --target-version 6.8
satellite-maintain upgrade run --target-version 6.8
```

But the problem is this command will expect user inputs `YES / NO / CANCEL` multiple times. Using "shell module" will not help us to give user input. DO we have any other options to view the command execution output in screen and provide input based our user requirement.

Comment: use a python|shell script with pexpect|expect

Comment: You can actually use the `shell` module and provide the input using the `stdin` parameter: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `action plugin` from https://gist.github.com/confiks/6d7b0ee3e137df01b758. All credits to its original author. Copied here the same as sometimes external links go bad. Note that, this is basic version and can be extensively tweaked based on requirement.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
Put this script in the action_plugins directory of your playbook directory.

**Usage**:

```
 - name: "Ask the user if we should continue."
   action: ask_key prompt="Continue? Yes / No / Random (y/n/r)?" accepted_keys="['y', 'n', 'r']"
   register: answer
```

**script named ask_key.py**

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

from ansible import constants as C
from ansible.errors import AnsibleError
from ansible.module_utils.parsing.convert_bool import boolean
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase

try:
    from __main__ import display
except ImportError:
    from ansible.utils.display import Display
    display = Display()

class ActionModule(ActionBase):
    TRANSFERS_FILES = False

    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        result = super(ActionModule, self).run(tmp, task_vars)

        result.update(
            dict(
                changed=False,
                failed=False,
                msg='',
                skipped=False
            )
        )

        self._supports_check_mode = True
        self._supports_async = False

        setup_module_args=dict(
            gather_subset='all',
            gather_timeout=10
        )

        setup_result = self._execute_module(
            delete_remote_tmp=True,
            module_name='setup',
            module_args=setup_module_args,
            persist_files=False,
            task_vars=task_vars,
            tmp=tmp,
            wrap_async=self._task.async
        )

        if setup_result['ansible_facts']['ansible_system'] != 'Linux':
            result['failed'] = True

        return result
```

Comment: Do I need to mention the action plugin after my shell module ? or where to incorporate the command: satellite-maintain upgrade check --target-version 6.8
satellite-maintain upgrade run --target-version 6.8

Comment: I have provided the usage task in above answer.  That task would prompt for y or n. User response will be stored in register called answer. You can evaluate it to make decision

Comment: in fact you can modify the plugin(python code) to `sys.exit(1)` when `n/N` is received.....